# Assigning a polygon shape to density values

Tags: mapbox, 3d, mapbox-studio

I am pretty new to GIS as a whole. I have a simple flat file in a `csv` format, as an example:

```
lat,long,name,val
25,40,abc,10
50,44,def,20
```

What I am trying to achieve is to assign a 3d polygon in Mapbox such as in this [example](https://blog.mapbox.com/3d-mapping-global-population-density-how-i-built-it-141785c91107). While the settings might be quite straight forward in Mapbox where you assign a height and color value based on a data range, it obviously does not work in my case.

I think I am missing out other files such as mentioned in the blog post, like shapefiles or some other file that is required to assign 3d layouts to the 3d extrusion.

I need to know what I am missing out in configuring a 3d polygon, say a cube in Mapbox based on the `val` data column in my CSV.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured what I was missing was the coordinates that make up the polygons I want to display. This can easily be defined in a `geojson` file format, if you are interested in the standards, refer [here](https://geojson.org/). For the visual I need, I would require:

1. **Points** (typically your long and lat coordinates)
2. **Polygon** (a square would require 5 vertices, the lines connecting and
   defining your polygon)
3. **Features** (your data points)
4. **FeatureCollection** (a collection of features)

This are all parts of the `geojson` format, I used Python and its `geojson` module which comes with everything I need to do the job.

---

Using a helper function below, I am able to compute square/rectangular boundaries based on a single point. The height and width defines how big the square/rectangle appears.

```
def create_rec(pnt, width = 0.00005, height = 0.00005):  
    pt1 = (pnt[0] - width, pnt[1] - height)  
    pt2 = (pnt[0] - width, pnt[1] + height)  
    pt3 = (pnt[0] + width, pnt[1] + height)  
    pt4 = (pnt[0] + width, pnt[1] - height)  
    pt5 = (pnt[0] - width, pnt[1] - height)  

    return Polygon([[pt1,pt2,pt3,pt4,pt5]]) #assign to a Polygon class from geojson
```

From there it is pretty straight forward to append them into list of features, `FeatureCollection` and output as a `geojson` file:

```
with open('path/coordinates.csv', 'r') as f:
    headers = next(f)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

transform = []

for i in data:
    #3rd last value is x and 2nd last is the y
    point = Point([float(i[-3]), float(i[-2])]) 
    polygon = create_rec(point['coordinates'])

    #in my case I used a collection to store both points and polygons
    col = GeometryCollection([point, polygon])

    properties = {'Name':i[0]}

    feature = Feature(geometry = col, properties = properties)
    transform.append(feature)

fc = FeatureCollection(transform)

with open('target_doc_u.geojson', 'w') as f:
    dump(fc, f)
```

The output file `target_doc_u` would contain all the listed items above that allows me to plot my point, as well as continue of the [blog post](https://blog.mapbox.com/3d-mapping-global-population-density-how-i-built-it-141785c91107) in Mapbox to assign my filled extrusion and set height based on my value property.